# Problem in appending a string to a already filled string builder(at the beginning by using INSERT) and then converting that to string array(C#3.0)

Tags: c#-3.0

I have a string builder like

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Value1");
sb.AppendLine("Value2");
```

Now I have a string  say

```
string str = "value 0";
```

I did

```
sb.Insert(0,str);
```

and then

```
string[] strArr = sb.ToString().Trim().Replace("\r", string.Empty).Split('\n');
```

The result I am getting as **(Array size of 2 where I should get 3)**

```
[0] value 0 Value1

[1] value2
```

But the desired output being

```
[0] Value 0
[1] Value1
[2] Value2
```

Where I am going wrong?

I am using C#3.0

Please help.. It 's urgent

Thanks

Comment: You should be aware that the performance advantage of using StringBuilder instead of string concatenation is lost if you insert at the beginning instead of using the Append methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [**`StringBuilder.Insert`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tyt41s0.aspx) does not insert a [new line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) automatically so you have to add one yourself:

```
string str = "value 0" + Environment.NewLine;
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you would get an array of size one. You put "Value1" in the StringBuilder when you create it, then you add "Value2" and a line break, making the string "Value1Value2\r\n" (assuming the CR+LF line break for this example). Then you insert "Value 0" at the beginning, making the string "Value 0Value1Value2\r\n". Trimming the string removes the line break at the end, and splitting on a character that doesn't exist in the string gives you an array with only one item:

```
[0] Value 0Value1Value2
```

The `Insert` method doesn't add a line break like `AppendLine` does, so you have to add the line break manually:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("Value1");
sb.AppendLine("Value2");

string str = "value 0";
sb.Insert(0, str + Environment.NewLine);
```

Now you can trim and split the string:

```
string[] strArr =
  sb.ToString()
  .Trim()
  .Split(new string[]{ Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting `Value 0` and which would result in the first line being `Value0Value1`

Insert will only insert a string at the specified position.  It does work the same as AppendLine. As there is no carriage return your split won't work as you intended.